How can I identify the abilities of my ESP32 module?
I was attempting to discover how to identify my ESP32 development board.
I was wondering how to discover the abilities it supports.
Here's a snapshot of my board:

This was related to a question I asked about which Arduino board to use.

I discovered the ESP Product Selector (official website) to answer this question.
Here's the board specs, dataheets and all the rest for my board.
Now you can

go to the main page
find your product in the list (bottom portion of page) and select it
Get all information

Make sure you match :

What is printed on your ESP32 on that main chip area
To the exact text in the list (on the web site).

You can see a graphic on the web site for the individual item so you can try to match the two.  Here's what mine looks like:

This will help you know you've got that exact one and then you can view the abilities listed for it.
In my case I was wondering about BLE and I discovered that these support BLE 4.2 (not 5.0) like newer ones.
What Site Looks Like: How To Use


You can click that to see the image to see if it matches what is on your chip

You can float over this area to see the details of specs - see the BLE is 4.2 example

This area can be scrolled and has all the details of your specific ESP32



You got an ESP32-WROOM-32. Here is the datasheet.
https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-wroom-32_datasheet_en.pdf
ESP32-WROOM-32 is a powerful, generic Wi-Fi + Bluetooth® + Bluetooth LE MCU module that targets a wide
variety of applications, ranging from low-power sensor networks to the most demanding tasks, such as voice
encoding, music streaming and MP3 decoding.
At the core of this module is the ESP32-D0WDQ6 chip*. The chip embedded is designed to be scalable and
adaptive. There are two CPU cores that can be individually controlled, and the CPU clock frequency is adjustable
from 80 MHz to 240 MHz. The chip also has a low-power coprocessor that can be used instead of the CPU to
save power while performing tasks that do not require much computing power, such as monitoring of
peripherals. ESP32 integrates a rich set of peripherals, ranging from capacitive touch sensors, SD card interface,
Ethernet, high-speed SPI, UART, I2S, and I2C.
You can make an advanced ESP32-WROOM-32E IoT Dev Board. This board will integrate temperature and humidity sensor, gas sensor etc. :
https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/Advanced_ESP32_WROOM_32E_IoT_Dev_Board_90812ac7.html
